# Open an activity after a certain amount of time?

Tags: android, android-activity, timer, splash-screen

I would like to implement a SplashScreen in my app. I found the best and easiest way is to  launch an activity that shows a layout with an image view at the launch of the app and then adding android:noHistory="true" attribute to the manifest.
Now, how do I set the splashscreen activity to launch the MainActivity class after a certain amount of time? Lets say 2 seconds?

This is my splashscreen activity

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
}
}
```

Comment: just a warning about using the flag no history - the systen will finish the activity anytime after any other activity is launched. This is quite out of the control of the application code. So do not release anything in the destroy function of the no_history activity . This will lead to unexpected and difficult to debug exceptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayinmilliseconds(2000 in your case));

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
       //start the new activity here.
    }
};
```

Comment: can you merge your code with mine please? I get errors whenever I try. Still a noob, sorry!

Comment: just declare a handler in the class. and use the code i have given in the onCreate() method after setContentView

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete sample.

```
package com.test.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class splash extends Activity {

    private static final int STOPSPLASH = 0;
    //time in milliseconds
    private static final long SPLASHTIME = 3000;a

    private ImageView splash;

    //handler for splash screen
    private Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.Handler#handleMessage(android.os.Message)
         */
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case STOPSPLASH:
                //remove SplashScreen from view
                splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
            splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = STOPSPLASH;
            splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, SPLASHTIME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TrackMyMoneyActivity extends Activity {
//member fields
private ProgressBar pbar = null;
private TextView counter_txt = null;
Thread splash_thread = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.splashpbar);
    counter_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countertxt);
    //define thread
    splash_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int i = 0;
              for( i=0;i<100;i++){

                  pbar.setProgress(i);

                 // counter_txt.setText(i+" %");
                  try {
                    splash_thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
              if(i==100){
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginApp.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
        }
    });
    splash_thread.start();

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();


}
```

}

I hope it will be solved your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `java.util.Timer` in this way:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
    public void run() { 
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}, 2000 /*amount of time in milliseconds before execution*/ );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Splashscreen extends Activity 
    {
  private static final int SPLASH_TIME = 10 * 1000;// 3 seconds


  Button logo;
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    try {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            Intent intent = new     Intent(Splashscreen.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            Splashscreen.this.finish();

            //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

        }


    }, SPLASH_TIME);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
                 } 
            }, SPLASH_TIME);
    } catch(Exception e){}
// METHOD 1     

/****** Create Thread that will sleep for 5 seconds *************/        
Thread background = new Thread() {
   public void run() {

       try {
           // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
           sleep(50*1000);

           // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
           Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);

           //Remove activity
           finish();

       } catch (Exception e) {

         }
       }
     };


     background.start();



      }
```